# Trying to remove Startup reg key

Tags: windows, cmd, key, registry, regedit

I want to run a batch to remove a reg key from the start up.

I created a test key and I'm running the command below

```
Reg Delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\Test" /F
```

But when I run the batch as Administrator I get the following error

"ERROR: `The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.`

The key does exist in the reg but it will not appear in the command prompt.

Can any see what is going wrong here? or what command do I need to do to remove this reg key?

Answer (score 0):

Replace **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`** with  **`HKLM`**

Type **`reg /?`** at the command line for proper syntax.